# Why app-check enforcement is not preventing me to login when app-check fails?

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, react-native-firebase, firebase-app-check

I have enforced app-check and I initialize it in the app but even if I give a wrong key just for testing it, I am still able to login. I have upgraded app-check to a newer version but before it used to work.

```
   async getAppCheck() {
      try {
         const rnfbProvider = await firebase.appCheck().newReactNativeFirebaseAppCheckProvider();
         rnfbProvider.configure({
            android: {
               provider: __DEV__ ? 'debug' : 'playIntegrity',
               debugToken: 'a07b3e55-4cc3-414f-a498-ffb66bebda6c',
            }
         });
    
         firebase.appCheck().initializeAppCheck({ provider: rnfbProvider, isTokenAutoRefreshEnabled: true })
            .then((res) => {
               console.log("initializeAppCheck: ", JSON.stringify(res));
            }).catch((error) => {
               console.error("app check failed: " + error);
            });
      } catch (e) {
         console.error("Failed to initialize appCheck:", e);
      }
   }
```

initializeAppCheck is always returning null (both when app-check passes and when it doesnt). Shouldnt it return a value that indicates whether is failed or passed?

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, from the moment you activate AppCheck, it takes a while for all requests to be verified. In addition, initializeAppCheck usually returns an instance of AppCheckService, in your case is it really always returning null?

Comment: @GabrielNexT it always returns null. The old version of it used to return the token.

Comment: @GabrielNexT managed to get the token using the getToken() function. However, I think its a bug that allows user to authenticate despite the fact app-check fails. A malicious user can still bypass my front-end check for token and authenticate. Backend should prevent that user to authenticate.

Answer (score 0):

eventhough this is not a solution I was able to to get the token using `getToken()` function. I then check if returned value is empty or not and allow the user to authenticate based on that.

Normally, firebase should prevent the user to authenticate if the app-check failed. Maybe, it still allows the user to authenticate if I am on debug mode but not in production, I haven't tested in prod yet. But if this is not the case, then this is definitely a bug that the Firebase team should take a look at.